# Connect MetaMask wallet in mobile phone browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, metamask, ethers.js, web3-react

Currently facing issues in trying to get to sign the wallet to get the address on my mobile phone browser, wanted to be able to connect it to a wallet (MetaMask pref.) installed on my mobile phone.

```
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);

    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const address = await signer.getAddress();

    console.log(address);
```

Is there any way to connect it with each other? It works well on a PC

Answer (score 1):

In mobile browser there is no extension support, so if you have installed **[metamask mobile app](https://metamask.io/download/)** on your phone, you can access your website in **Metamask's dApp browser**.

Also you can use libraries like [web3modal](https://github.com/WalletConnect/web3modal) or [web3-react](https://github.com/Uniswap/web3-react), which can handle mobile crypto wallet connections.

Comment: Does this also provide a way to call a Smart Contract? Seems like it errors me out when I try to make a connection.
`//Get Smart Contract Address
      const ERC721 = new ethers.Contract(
        "*contract address*",
        ERC721ABI,
        provider
      );`

Comment: The code to call contract functions will be same as the desktop browser, only the web3 provider will be changed.